# Which sentence is better, "campus" or "school","be beneficial to" or " be good for"? "children's bodies and minds" or "children's body and mind"?

Tags: sentence-construction

My son (he's 7) constructed 2 sentences:

> 1. Let's make our school evergreen all the year round. The plants will **be beneficial to** **children's body and mind**.
> 2. Let's make our campus evergreen all the year round. The plants will **be good for children's bodies and minds**.

Which sentence is better?

Comment: The second one is **correct**, the first isn't. Reason being you need bodies and minds because there is more than 1 child being talked of here.

Comment: I would write- Good for children. It covers everything. @MamtaD

Comment: Agreed @RuchirM when we are talking about 'health', simply putting 'good for 'x'' certainly works. In fact, this makes sentence much better IMO! :)

Comment: Just a little suggestion: don't accept the answer too quickly. Let others come in. Here we have brilliant minds! :) thanks for accepting anyway.

Comment: Suggestion accepted. I'll look forward to more brilliant minds here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those two, the second is preferred.

**However**...

If the context is [**not** of a shrub/tree](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evergreen_1?q=evergreen), 'evergreen' may sound improper. In all other contexts, 'evergreen' **first** represents - popular/famous. Say -"An evergreen series of 'Friends'". If someone calls your 'school evergreen' what comes **first** in my mind is the school is famous and popular.

However, in case of 'places', it is very common to write just 'green'. For example, we have a campaign like...

> Clean Mumbai, Green Mumbai

While talking of making any **place green**, we mean planting trees or preserving them.

So, I'd say

> Let's make our campus green (because it's the campus precisely, not the school).

Now the second part.

When we talk about the scientific or any such facts, we use present tense.

> Raisins will be good for health ~ not preferred 
>  Raisins **are** god for health - preferred.

So, let's change the tense.

> Plants **are** good for...

Third part - children's bodies and minds.

You are talking about many bodies and minds collectively. So, it's children's bodies and minds.

[Check NCBI's page here.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20715603)

*But for a 7-yr-old kid, a very good attempt!* :)